# TinyMCE editor formatting creates unwanted 200b characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unicode, tinymce

I have a TinyMCE editor on my page. Content added to the editor:

jfdkl

**​jfdslk**

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent({"format":"raw"})
```

returns this:

```
"<p>jfdkl</p><p><strong data-mce-bogus="1">​jfdslk</strong><br></p>"
```

Copy that to vim editor:

```
"<p>jfdkl</p><p><strong data-mce-bogus="1"><200b>jfdslk</strong><br></p>"
```

The issue is with this extra **<200b>** string. This inserts a **?** character in my MySQL database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've found it's the autoresize TinyMCE plugin that adds this stuff: [issue resolved here](http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=26266)

Answer (score 0):

This should not happen, but there are lots of possibilities that can insert special characters into an editor. Best option will be to remove this character before saving to DB - eighter on server-side or on client-side (use the tinymce `onSubmit` event).